# Is creating Azure BlobContainerClient instance is heavy operation using Azure Java SDK

Tags: azure

I have requirement to upload multiple files at fixed interval to Azure blob container

Please suggest if I can create the BlobContainerClient instance and cache the same in my application to reuse it further. If yes I am not sure if this cached BlobContainerClient instance will be invalided and after what time it will invalid and is there any way to keep it live.

Comment: How are you creating the instance?

Comment: BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(blobConnString).buildClient();

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a shared `HttpClient` instance (basically the underlying connection pool etc. for the REST API call) to it, it should not be a heavy operation.

AFAIK, cached Client instance will not be invalided, if you use `connectionString`, unless the access key get revoked.